# Android How to Remove( " )Character from String

Tags: android, string, replace, character

I wanted to to Remove ( " ) Character from String

This is my text

> "69452;6486699"

I need to Have This Text

> 69452;6486699

I've tryed to use String.Replace

```
 text = text.replace(""","");
```

and does not work

Also I've Use This Way

```
 text = text.replace("/"","");
```

But Not Again

Any One Can Help me ?!

Comment: Click on the tick below the desired answer to accept it (all three are pretty much the same) and officially mark the question as `solved` ;)

Comment: I know mate But I should wait 10 min and i don't have any time to wait

Comment: oh right lol, I didn't realize they hadn't passed

Answer (score 40, accepted):

use this code

```
text.replace("\"", "");
```

Backslash () is used for escaping special characters, forward slash (/) is just a regular character with no special meaning in the string.

Answer (score 6):

Wrong slash. Do it with a backslash:

```
text = text.replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: I might be nitpicking, but it's `replace(String, String)` instead of `Replace(String, String)` (methods in Java start with a small letter)

Answer (score 5):

It's

```
text = text.replace("\"", "");
```

Backslash (`\`) is used for escaping special characters, forward slash (`/`) is just a regular character with no special meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You need to try like this

```
text = text.replace("\"", "");
```

Look into [String.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)